# Algorithmically correcting noisy distance measurements between data points on a number line

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning

I have an application where I have data points `x` that can be mapped to a number line. However, I don't know what their value on the number line is. Fortunately, I don't need to know *exactly* what their values are, I just need to know what the distances between the points are (i.e. the 0-point on the number line is arbitrary, and it can be reflected without affecting anything).

I have as input a set of transitive distance measurements `D[i,j]` between the points. Additionally, the distance measurements are oriented (i.e. `D[i,j] = -D[j,i]`, with `D[i,j] > 0` indicating that `x[i]` is further to the right on the number line than `x[j]`).

First challenge: I don't have all of the values of `D`, but I do have some control over which values I obtain.

Ideally, this wouldn't be that big of a problem because I could choose the pairs `[i,j]` so that `D` forms a spanning tree (interpreting it as an adjacency matrix of a graph) and then the distance between `x[i]` and `x[j]` would be the path length of the walk between nodes `i` and `j` on the tree. Unfortunately...

Second challenge: the distance measurements are noisy. In most cases, the noise is small. However, in rare cases the distance measurements are WILDLY inaccurate.

So. The problem. I would like to use multiple distance measurements between the data points to denoise these noisy distance measurements. Here's my wish list, some of which may turn out to be infeasible:

- An algorithm that maps the points in `x` to the number line (with an arbitrary 0-point) so that there is a single, unambiguous, transitive distance between any `x[i]` and `x[j]`, and it is clear which one is to the right of the other.
- The algorithm works with a graph `D` that is sparse, but not a tree. Perhaps it has the property that there are at least 2 paths between any two nodes.
- Because the multiple paths through `D` between two points represent different prospective distance measurements, use some loss function that minimizes the difference of the inter-data point distances in the projection to some integrated value of the distances implied by `D`.
- The algorithm uses a loss function that saturates for high values. This would take care of the case where the distances are very inaccurate, but I'm worried it would also make the problem non-convex. L1 penalty might be good enough.

My first thought was to look into the multidimensional scaling literature since it's concerned with distance-preserving embeddings, but I don't think my problem is posed correctly. MDS seems to assume that you have a single, unambiguous distance measurement between each point. That's not my set up.

I'm interested in any literature or algorithms people can point me to, whether for some aspect of this problem, or for a similar problem, or for roughly the same problem. Thanks!

Comment: Are errors in D correlated for multiple distance measurements using one of the same points? Another way of asking this is: is the error in D from erroneous distance calculation, or from erroneous measurement of where points actually are? E.g. say D[p,q] gives a value that erroneously places q 2 units too far to the right of p. If we assume p is fixed in its correct place, does that mean that for point r to the right of q, D[q,r] will have an error that includes placing q 2 units too close to the left of r?

Comment: I believe they will be independent. In any case, solving the independent case would probably be easier, and it would still be a step forward for me.

Comment: If you were not aware, there is a SE site for Statistics, ML, and other related topics called [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/). You can also get good answers in that site for more theoretical questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can put up with the L1 norm, I think you can minimize this as a linear programming problem - which also tells you that it is a convex problem, so a variety of other techniques, such as simple hill-climbing and iteratively reweighted least squares, should converge to a global minimum.

Arbitrarily set X0 = 0.

For each pair Xi, Xj for which you have measurements add Xi - Xj - Dij <= Tij, Dij - Xi + Xj <= Tij, where Dij is the measurement

Minimise SUM_ij Tij - this is minimised at Tij = |Xi - Xj - Dij|, so this minimizes the sum of L1 norms of errors.

Comment: Nice! This looks right to me. Follow up question. Let's say I pose the question in this way, is there an algorithmic approach that would give me something like slackness variables that I could use to heuristically detect these wildly inaccurate measurements? I'm thinking that a few of the `D[i,j]` might give very tight constraints, and I could use those to choose some measurements to throw out and then rerun the algorithm.

Comment: If you are looking to discard some observations, I would look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_sample_consensus or something similar - perhaps using a RANSAC-like algorithm to attempt to hillclimb to the fit that minimizes the sum of absolute error using 95% of observations, from multiple random starts.

Answer (score 0):

After giving a gook look to your post I consider that an interesting approach would be to use [Ensemble learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ensemble_learning).

Extracting from the great book [Artificial Intelligence: A Modern Approach (3rd. Ed.)](https://dcs.abu.edu.ng/staff/abdulrahim-abdulrazaq/courses/cosc208/Artificial%20Intelligence%20A%20Modern%20Approach%20(3rd%20Edition).pdf), page 748:

> The idea of ensemble learning methods is to select a **collection**, or ensemble, of hypotheses from the hypothesis  space and **combine their predictions** For example, during cross-validation  we might generate twenty different decision trees, and have them vote on the best classification for a new example.

The most widely used ensemble method is the one called **boosting algorithms**. Here is a [page](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2015/11/quick-introduction-boosting-algorithms-machine-learning/) that explains more about them (also explained on the pages following p.748 of the AI book). Basically you could generate `K` *new* distance metrics plus your current one, combine them in an ensemble classifier, and obtain the average (sometimes weighted average) of their predictions to obtain a more precise one.

Something really **important** to notice is that those `K` metrics (or hypotheses) are assumed to be *independent from each other*, as also explained in the same cited book and page:

> But if the hypotheses are at least a little bit different, thereby reducing the correlation between their errors [*in other words: independent*], then ensemble learning can be very useful.

I do recommend you take a look at that book, as it contain *many* relevant information that could help you with your projects. Hope this is useful.

**Note:** This approach has worked for me before in projects related to computer vision and object detection (also *quite* noisy data most of the time). It helped reduce classification errors after choosing good `K` hypotheses.